# Java equivalent of Buffer.BlockCopy

Tags: java, vb.net

What is the Java equivalent of VB's *Buffer.BlockCopy*?

```
for (int i = 0; i < num5; i++) {
    int[] dst = new int[9];
    // Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, (num2 + &HF8) + (i * 40), dst, 0, 40)
    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[dst[4] - 1];
    // Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, dst(5), buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length)
}
```

Notice the commented out section... I don't know a Java equivalent to put there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand this properly, I think you want `System.arraycopy()`. [The JavaDoc for it can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

A quick example would be:

```
int[] src = new int[3] {1,2,3};
int[] dst = new int[4];
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, 3); // Copies all of src into dst starting at zero.
// Dst would be {1,2,3,0}
```

Comment: @Jire my answer didn't help then? :p I thought I just beat Todd in the SO answer race! I guess he did provide an example...

Comment: Weird this is a `System` method

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a direct equivalent. The closest match is [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). However, this can't be used when source and destination arrays are of different primitive types (as in your example you use byte[] and int[]).

Comment: I think I can use _arraycopy_ on different primitive types. I used it in the scenario and it compiled just fine.

Comment: @Jire I think you will get an ArrayStoreException at runtime, as per the javadoc. Give it a shot and let us know!

Comment: I have an ArrayStoreException, indeed! =/

Answer (score 0):

in java
System.arraycopy with the same type name from source Array to dest.

within C#/VB I can copy a float array to another type(eg. byte[]).

```
  float[] floats = [1.2,4.0,3.5,12];

  // Copy to bytes
  byte[] result = new byte[floats.Length * sizeof(short)];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(floats, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
```